# Update to IntelliJ 2017.1 causes JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to print

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This morning I updated to IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1, when I run any of my tests, and even run a hello_world project I made, the console prints a message stating `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentpath:"C:\windows\FireEye\JavaAgentDll_00.dll"` after executing my program.

Also, when I try to run in debug mode I receive the error:

`ERROR: JDWP unable to get necessary JVMTI capabilities.`

If I run the program outside of IntelliJ I do not receive these errors. Is there a solution to resolving the error and is there a reason the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is now "picked up"?

Comment: This is a feature, not a bug. Prior editions ignored the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTS` environment variable. There are several places in IntelliJ config where you can override env vars, if need be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html) environment variable from the system or configure the run/debug configuration to not include parent environment:

[image: environment]

Comment: Any idea how to solve this for Gradle builds? Ideally, globally and not per project. There is no similar checkbox for Gradle-based builds/tests.

Comment: If you want to solve it globally, remove the global environment variable set in your operating system.

Comment: It's not set globally. I believe FireEye intercepts calls to the JDK and adds that option. And FireEye is required by our corporate security. This has only become a problem in IDEA since I upgraded to 2017.1, so there needs to be a work around.

Comment: Does adding `idea.no.launcher=true` into Help | Edit Custom Properties help?

Comment: I didn't try that, but I solved the issue. 2017.1 was the first version I installed with the Toolbox app. It changed where my settings were loaded from. When I manually changed the `idea.system.path` and `idea.config.path` back to the old locations in `idea.properties` everything started to work again. I looked for a reference to fireeye or JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in the new, non-working configuration and could not find any.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by adding the following command into idea.bat file:

```
UNSET JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
```

I'm running IntelliJ 2017.1 on Windows 7, and my idea.bat file is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1\bin` folder.

The top 5 lines of my idea.bat file looks like these after the changes:

```
@ECHO OFF
UNSET JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS 
::----------------------------------------------------------------------
:: IntelliJ IDEA startup script.
::----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem at work.  This is probably FireEye knowledge rather than an IntelliJ answer, but I find that when I run IntelliJ as administrator the problem goes away without any settings changes, so this works if you have admin access to the development box.

Note that if you start IntelliJ from the IDEA toolbox then the toolbox also needs to be run as adminstrator.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to override the env is from the from the Help | Edit Custom VM Options menu of all places.

[image: IntelliJ_Help_VMopt]