# How to ignore JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS for a particular jar?

Tags: java, jar

Installing FireEye sets `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and when launching my application jar, following message is shown and jar is not launched:

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
>   -agentpath:"C:\Windows\FireEye\JavaAgentDll_00.dll" Cannot open project

Following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008661/update-to-intellij-2017-1-causes-java-tool-options-to-print) suggested to unset the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` variable but I don't want to change global settings. Is there an option to bypass this variable check(i.e. ignore `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`) while launching my jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use batch file like this.

```
@setlocal
@set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=
java -jar your.jar
@endlocal
```